# Removing the last comma separator in each list

Tags: javascript, jquery, separator

I have a series of unordered lists wrapped in another unordered list. The task is to separate the individual li tags with commas and omitting the each list's last li tag.

I can do it on an individual list level i.e. When testing with just one list I was able to remove the last comma from the last element. But when I'm trying to apply the JavaScript in affects the last li element of the wrapping ul...

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.tagsList li span').each(function () {
                    $(this).append(',');
                });
                var lTag = $('.tagsList li:last span').text().replace(',','');
                $('.tagsList li:last span').text(lTag);
            });

</script>
<ul class="postsList">
    <li>
        <ul class="tagsList">
            <li><span>tag1</span></li>
            <li><span>tag2</span></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
<li>
    <ul class="tagsList">
        <li><span>tag1</span></li>
        <li><span>tag2</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe even CSS suffices: `.tagsList > li + li:before { content: "," }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a slightly modified selector

```
$('.tagsList li:not(:last-child) span').each(function () {
    $(this).append(',');
});
```

This directly target all the `span` elements inside a `li` except the last `li` of each list.

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wwTjH/2/

Comment: any thoughts on how to add the comment to all but the last child?

Comment: @chris, it is adding to all but the `last-child`.. if you want to add to all but the last `li` of all the `li`s then change `:last-child` to `:last`